# unresolved reference "Settings" in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to write some value in the System Settings property using **putInt** but getting an error. The compiler says "Unresolved Reference Settings". Please check the below code -

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.contentResolver, SETTINGS_1, shutterOpen)
Settings.System.putInt(context.contentResolver, SETTINGS_2, muted)
```

Can anyone please help? Do I have to import anything extra for using this function? I am quite new in Kotlin and having really a hard time fixing it due to resource constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `import android.provider.Settings;`

Tips: In Android Studio, wait for auto-complete to appear then press tab or enter. The required package will be imported automatically.

[image]